# Skip Row In CSV If Contains Strings From List

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv

I have a list of approximately 500 strings that I want to check against a CSV file containing 25,000 rows. What I currently have seems to be getting stuck looping. I basically want to skip the row if it contains any of the strings in my string list and then extract other data.

```
stringList = [] #strings look like "AAA", "AAB", "AAC", etc.

with open('BadStrings.csv', 'r')as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in filereader:
        stringToExclude = row[0]
        stringList.append(stringToExclude)

with open('OtherData.csv', 'r')as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(filereader, None) #Skip header row
    for row in filereader:
        for s in stringList:
            if s not in row:
                data1 = row[1]
```

Edit: Not an infinite loop, but looping is taking too long.

Comment: I don’t see how you get in an infinite loop. I do see a problem with overwriting data1 each time s is not in row. This will probably happen often for every row, since you check for every s in stringList separately. I would restructure your second for loop and the if-statement. Maybe use a continue statement.

Comment: @NielsHenkens I assumed it was infinitely looping after a couple test runs of not completing even after 30+ minutes. Don't think it should be taking that long...is there any way to make it loop quicker?

Comment: I take it that row or row[0] is not just the string s, but could contain s? Otherwise you could’ve reversed the if statement with something like ‘if row[x] in stringList:’. That would’ve speeded things up a lot. One thing to optimize is that your ‘if s not in row:’ is not correct not optimal. Right now, if one of the strings of stringList is in row, then data1 will still get update 499 times. I don’t think that this is your desired behavior.

Comment: @NielsHenkens Yes. Row is not just the string s, but contains s.

Answer (score 0):

according to Niels I would change the 2 loop and iterate over the row itself and check if the current row entry is inside the "bad" list:

```
for row in filereader:
    for s in row:
       if s not in stringlist:
           data1 = row[0]
```

And I also dont know what you want to do with data1 but you always change the object reference when an item is not in stringList.
You could use a list to add the items to a list with `data1.append(item)`

Comment: Your answer is not what I meant. Not knowing what row looks like exactly, but this solution only works if an item of row is exactly the value you want to check for in stringList (and not a longer string containing part of the unwanted substring from stringList). And you are also looping over all items in row and still updating data1 for every item of row that isn’t in stringList.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
stringList = [] #strings look like "AAA", "AAB", "AAC", etc.

with open('BadStrings.csv', 'r')as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in filereader:
        stringToExclude = row[0]
        stringList.append(stringToExclude)

data1 = [] # Right now you are overwriting your data1 every time. I don't know what you want to do with it, but you could for exmaple add all row[1] to a list data1
with open('OtherData.csv', 'r')as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(filereader, None) #Skip header row
    for row in filereader:
        found_s = False
        for s in stringList:
            if s in row:
                found_s = True
                break
        if not found_s:
            data1.append(row[1]) # Add row[1] to the list is no element of stringList is found in row.
```

Still probably not a huge performance improvement, but at least the for loop `for s in stringList:` will now stop after s is found.